# Scss & Vue (need result like in image)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, sass

I need to do coins like in image, i tried to do this, but i dont understand how to apply styles for not first item in a flex row with wrap

can somebody help me?

Vue

```
<div class="coins__images">
      <img
        ref="img"
        class="coins__img"
        src="wallet/coin.png"
        v-for="coin of coinsQuantity"
        :key="coin"
      />
    </div>
```

Scss

```
&__images {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  &__img {
    z-index: 100;

    @for $i from 1 through 100 {
      &:nth-child(#{$i + 1}) {
        z-index: calc(100 - #{$i});
        // transform: translateX(-10px);
        // transform: translateX(calc(-#{$i} * 10px));
        // background-color: red;
      }
    }
  }
```

If i apply styles like above I expecting required result only in desktop, but when changing screen width (resize from desktop to tablet or mobile) my coins are disappear from area of ​​visibility
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LywPp.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a slightly different approach and add a wrapper div with smaller width around each coin, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2q0xupLj/). In your example it would be something like this:

VUE

```
<div class="coins__images">
  <div class="coins__imgwrapper"
      v-for="coin of coinsQuantity"
      :key="coin">
    <img
      ref="img"
      class="coins__img"
      src="wallet/coin.png"
    />
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
&__images {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

&__imgwrapper {
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 100;

  @for $i from 1 through 100 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i + 1}) {
      z-index: calc(100 - #{$i});
    }
  }
}

&__img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, u r truly a genuis